# Parse error when using asp:ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

I am trying to create a clickable image that when clicked, goes to a dynamic url. I have tried this a few ways but seem to be missing something.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Copy">
    <asp:ItemTemplate>
        <a href="../PricingTool/PriceListCopy.aspx?PriceListID=<%# Eval("PriceListID") %>" runat="server" ID="lnkCopy" ><asp:Image runat="server" src="../../Images/plus.gif" /></a>
    </asp:ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The above code causes a Parse error (The server tag is not well formed.)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Copy">
    <asp:ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkCopy" NavigateUrl="../PricingTool/PriceListCopy.aspx?PriceListID=<%# Eval("PriceListID") %>" ><asp:Image runat="server" src="../../Images/plus.gif" /></asp:HyperLink>
    </asp:ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This above code gives me the same Parser error. Both errors occur on the asp:HyperLink and a href fields respectively.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:-

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Copy">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <a href='<%# String.Format("../PricingTool/PriceListCopy.aspx?PriceListID={0}",
                            Eval("PriceListID")) %>' runat="server" id="lnkCopy">
     <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="../../Images/plus.gif" /></a>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

First of all you were mixing double quotes with single thus it was throwing error as soon as it encounters double quote present in `Eval` method.

Apart from this, since you are using `<asp:Image` no need to include HTML img tag again, you can directly assign the image in `ImageUrl` property.

Comment: Thank you. Editing the silly mistake adding the asp: in my ItemTemplate tag and using the string format property, this now works really well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting double quotes on your href attribute value in the first example and the same for your NavigateUrl on the second.  Replace the outer or inner double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: Thank you. That did get rid of the error. But the image is not showing up with either the asp:Hyperlink nor the a tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be `<ItemTemplate>` without the `asp:` prefix:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Copy">
    <ItemTemplate>
        ...
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```